# Сортировка массива строк в js

Tags: javascript

Вообщем у меня есть проект на vue и там перед выводом массива с временными зонами я его сортирую. Массив выглядит примерно так:

```
arrTimeZone:Array[415] {
  0:Object {
    text:"(+00:00) Абиджане, Кот-д'Ивуар"
    value:"Africa/Abidjan"
  },
  1:Object {
    text:"(+00:00) Аккра, Гана"
    value:"Africa/Accra"
  },
  ...
```

Вообщем как видно из разпечатки их там 415, грубо говоря все зоны которые указаны в php. Вообщем после сортировки массив выглядит так, сначало идут все +0, потом +1, ..., +12 и после всего этого уже идёт -0, -1 и т.д.

Сортирую я вот так:

```
timeZoneSort.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.text > b.text) {
    return 1
  }
  if (a.text < b.text) {
    return -1
  }
  return 0
});
```

Обычная сортировка по возрастанию. Вопрос как заставить минусы идти впереди?? Чтобы массив начинался с -12, и заканчивался + 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, можно много чего тут сделать, но я бы привела это к числу.

```
timeZoneSort.sort(function (a, b) {
  let a_num = a.text.slice(1, 7)
  a_num = a_num.replace(':', '.')
  let p = a_num[0] == '+' ? 1 : 0
  a_num = Number(a_num) + p

  let b_num = b.text.slice(1, 7)
  b_num = b_num.replace(':', '.')
  p = b_num[0] == '+' ? 1 : 0
  b_num = Number(b_num) + p

  if (a_num > b_num) {
    return 1
  }
  if (a_num < b_num) {
    return -1
  }
  return 0
});
```

Примерно так. Я не тестировала, возможны опечатки

Comment: Вроде всё правильно отсортировалось.